# Regex - Getting the shortest text containing a given token

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

can this be done using only one regular expression?

Edit: Please, don't complain about me parsing HTML :) The same situation can be reproduced with plain text :

**Supposed source string:**

```
Lorem 1 ipsum. Lorem 2 ipsum TOKEN 
foo. Lorem 3 ipsum
```

**Supposed source string HTML version:**

```
<div id="entry-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="entry-2">Lorem ipsum TOKEN</div>
<div id="entry-3">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**What I want to get:**

**2**, because that "Lorem ipsum" contains the token.

I'm trying it using: `/([0-9]+).*TOKEN/sm`, but I get 1, because it starts looking for TOKEN after finding the first "digit", that is 1.

Using two separated regex/preg_match it's easy, but I wonder if this approach could be improved.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: *What I want to get: 2*, try `echo 2;` :)

Comment: Regexes + html = [Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) will come and clip-clop all over your face.

Answer (score 2):

Try the non-greedy *

```
/entry-([0-9]+).*?TOKEN/sm
```

Doesn't work on all platforms, but it might work in that (is that javascript?)

Comment: As far as I could understood and could test the non-greedy behaviour would avoid finding a longer string containing 2 tokens, it will stop after finding the first one. It's PHP btw. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a positive lookbehind to make sure that you match TOKEN, like so:

```
<div id="entry-([0-9]+)">.*(?<=TOKEN)</div>
```

You can use it like this:

```
$result = preg_match('%<div id="entry-([0-9]+)">.*(?<=TOKEN)</div>%i', $subject, $matches);
```

This will match the second example, but not the first or third.

Comment: It only works if the text containing the token is single line, even if I add the ms modifiers :( See it here: http://www.ideone.com/VyO6n

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct, but the problem is with the `s` modifier which causes `.` to match newline too and this makes your regex match the `1`. Drop the `s`.

Also you don't need the `m` modifier as you are not using anchors in your regex.

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/9BjYo)

This answer assumes that the `entry-[0-9]` and the TOKEN are on the same line in the input.

Comment: I need the s and m modifiers because the text containing the TOKEN could have several lines :( Like here: http://www.ideone.com/KryNE Thanks for that link, very useful.